# My Unity project contains empty compiler errors that stop me from entering play mode. How do I resolve them?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a project with a friend, we are using git for version control. They created the unity project and I pulled it to my computer as well. Every time I open the project, I have 2 blank compiler errors. I cannot click on them to open VS because they seemingly do not exist.
I can confirm as well we are using the same unity version (2019.2.15f1) both on Windows machines (mine is Win10)

Here is a list of things I have tried as suggested by other forums and my teammate:

1. Deleting and recreating library folder (results varied from no effect to unity no longer launching)
2. Creating a new directory and launching a fresh version (worked correctly on their system, not mine)
3. Reinstalling Unity
4. Triple checking that my version is up to date
5. Reinstalling Unity and Visual Studio
6. Changing the scripting framework (suggestion was to downgrade from 4 to 3.5, we were already on 2 for some reason)

Edit: Here's a picture of the errors 
[image]

Edit 2: Attempted to open new project in older version of unity, the following error appeared [image]

Edit 3: Upgraded to Unity v 2020.1.0a14
Edit 4: Never mind, now it's not even letting me open the project anymore. Complete with a cool fun new error.[image]
Edit 5: It just... started working. I reinstalled unity again and it just decided to work.

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of the errors? I think that'll likely be helpful for this question.

Comment: What folders were included in the git repository

Comment: I think we put everything in the repository @BugFinder but we have a gitignore now that should be excluding OBJ, Library, etc.

Comment: Try some basic debugging: start a new Unity project and see if it compiles?

Comment: Id suggest close unity,  removing temp, library, obj, etc and any that were there from the gitignore default suggestion from unity, and then startup unity.. do both machines have internet connections?

Comment: @Haney
I made a new project and it worked.
Then I added a blank script and it gained a blank error.

Comment: are you sure you installed the unity tools for visual studio?

Comment: I think so, I literally uninstalled unity this morning and reinstalled it with the visual studio option selected. Even though I don't use VS as my editor.

Comment: what are you using as an editor? .. going back versions in unity has always been complex, and generally doesnt work, so, it does seem odd that you make a new project, add an empty script and it creates an error...   What antivirus do you have?? (some tend to cause issues with random stuff)

Comment: I use Notepad++ to edit my code and Malwarebytes free as antivirus, but I don't think I've run it since my last unity install.

Comment: [Unity forums post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/four-blank-errors-in-each-new-project.599980/), [cross-site duplicate](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/177434/im-getting-empty-errors-unity-2019-2-14f1-windows-10). Found by searching Google for "unity blank errors"

Comment: Wow, yeah, weirdly enough I did google it and try the suggestions in other forum posts before deciding to post my own. In fact, in case you didn't notice, not only are my errors noticeably different, but I also, in fact, tried the solution from that post.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your project use some packages that aren't installed in your project.

Try to re import the packages mentioned in this image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwimW.png)